Edgedb in docker starting and stops after migration applied
I am facing odd issue when running egdedb server in Docker: it stops after migration apply without any useful info about what is happening.

Docker-compose:

version: '3.9'

volumes:
  edgedb_meta:
  edgedb_data:

services:
  wissance_ubs_db:
    container_name: wissance_ubs_db
    volumes:
      - edgedb_meta:/dbschema
      - edgedb_data:/var/lib/edgedb/data
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Edgedb.Dockerfile
    # stdin_open: true
    # tty: true
    env_file: ./deploy_settings.env
    ports:
      - "5656:5656"
    expose:
      - "5656"

  wissance_ubs_webapi_backend:
    container_name: wissance_ubs_webapi_backend
    depends_on:
      wissance_ubs_db:
        condition: service_started    
    volumes:
      - edgedb_meta:/root/.config/edgedb/credentials
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Wissance.Ubs.Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file: ./deploy_settings.env
    ports:
      - "8228:8228"



Edgedb Dockerfile

FROM edgedb/edgedb:4.7 AS base
VOLUME /dbschema

#WORKDIR /dbschema/
WORKDIR /opt

# according to doc above migrations should be placed to /dbschema/migrations
COPY ./src/Wissance.Ubs/Wissance.Ubs.Data/dbschema /dbschema
# copy toml
COPY ./src/Wissance.Ubs/Wissance.Ubs.Data/edgedb.toml /dbschema
COPY ./docs/data_init/init.eql /dbschema
# COPY PY CFG MAKER
COPY ./utils/edgedb_cfg_writer.py /dbschema

# PYTHON INSTALLING IN /usr/bin
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3 -y

# copy credentials file to volume
# configure EdgeDb
ARG EDGEDB_SERVER_PASSWORD=_mySuperPass_
ARG EDGEDB_SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME=Wissance_Ubs
RUN /usr/bin/python3 /dbschema/edgedb_cfg_writer.py
RUN cp /root/.config/edgedb/credentials/${EDGEDB_SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME}.json /dbschema

CMD ["edgedb-server"]


Part of env file:

EDGEDB_DOCKER_APPLY_MIGRATIONS=always
EDGEDB_DOCKER_LOG_LEVEL=debug
EDGEDB_DOCKER_BOOTSTRAP_TIMEOUT_SEC=3600

EDGEDB_SERVER_PASSWORD=_mySuperPass_
EDGEDB_SERVER_TLS_CERT_MODE=generate_self_signed
EDGEDB_SERVER_ADMIN_UI=enabled
EDGEDB_SERVER_SECURITY=insecure_dev_mode
EDGEDB_SERVER_HTTP_ENDPOINT_SECURITY=optional
EDGEDB_SERVER_BINARY_ENDPOINT_SECURITY=optional
EDGEDB_SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME=Wissance_Ubs
EDGEDB_SERVER_EMIT_SERVER_STATUS=true
EDGEDB_SERVER_COMPILER_POOL_SIZE=64

Screenshot with result:

Text log:
wissance_ubs_db              | Applied m1e4lbd2auubps6tx5sy5emdys4y2hrll3owcrxxxa66wsidu223fq (00001.edgeql)
wissance_ubs_db              | INFO 45 2024-05-13T06:41:30.617 edb.server: Connection established to backend database: edgedb
wissance_ubs_webapi_backend  | dbug: Quartz.Core.QuartzSchedulerThread[0]
wissance_ubs_webapi_backend  |       Batch acquisition of 0 triggers
wissance_ubs_db              | INFO 45 2024-05-13T06:41:35.558 edb.server: introspecting database 'edgedb'
wissance_ubs_db              | INFO 45 2024-05-13T06:41:36.319 edb.server: Connection established to backend database: edgedb
wissance_ubs_db              | INFO 45 2024-05-13T06:41:37.021 edb.server: Received signal: 15.
wissance_ubs_db              | INFO 45 2024-05-13T06:41:39.167 edb.server: Shutting down.
wissance_ubs_db              | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-funcs.sh: line 1327:    45 Killed                  gosu "${EDGEDB_SERVER_UID}" env -i "${pg_vars[@]}" "${EDGEDB_SERVER_BINARY}" "${server_opts[@]}"

I would like to quickly fix if it possible or understand what is happening (no exact reason)

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the error in plain text?

@DavidMaze, post was edited, text of issue was added. I left the image just as graphical prove of a issue
